# Error in my Ruby code...or Rails route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, partial-views

I'm relatively new to Ruby/Rails and have screwed up the structure of a `case/when` clause or perhaps I'm not understanding the routes...

Error in browser simply: `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"masters"}`

but clearly looking at `rake routes` I see:

```
 master GET   /masters/:id(.:format)    {:action=>"show", :controller=>"masters"}
 breeder GET  /breeders/:id(.:format)   {:action=>"show", :controller=>"breeders"}
```

and both (`masters` & `breeders`) controllers have working `show` methods...

where's my goof?

```
#app/controllers/dogs_controller.rb
class DogsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @parent = parent_object
    @dog = @parent.dogs.create(params[:dog])
    puts parent_path
    redirect_to parent_path(@parent)
  end

  def destroy
    @parent = parent_object
    @dog = @parent.dogs.find(params[:id])
    @dog.destroy
    redirect_to parent_path(@parent)
  end

  private

  def parent_object
    case 
      when params[:master_id] then Master.find(params[:master_id]) && parent_path = master_path
      when params[:breeder_id] then Breeder.find(params[:breeder_id]) && parent_path = breeder_path
    end
  end
end
```

**Edit:** Added MastersController

```
#app/controllers/masters_controller.rb
class MastersController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :html, :json

    def index
        respond_with(@masters = Master.all)
    end

    def show
        respond_with(@master = Master.find(params[:id]))
    end

    def new
        respond_with(@master = Master.new)
    end

    def edit
        respond_with(@master = Master.find(params[:id]))
    end

    def create
         @master = Master.new(params[:master])
         flash[:notice] = 'Master was successfully created.' if @master.save
         respond_with(@master) 
    end

    def update
        @master = Master.find(params[:id])
        flash[:notice] = 'Master has been updated.' if @master.update_attributes(params[:master])
        respond_with(@master)
    end

    def destroy
        @master = Master.find(params[:id])
        flash[:notice] = 'Successfully deleted master.' if @master.destroy
        respond_with(@master)
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you show the MastersController?

Comment: ok. it's pretty boilerplate but i added it.

Comment: Please explain the exact steps you're taking to get that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ha! Found it! My redirects were wrong... should have been `redirect_to @parent` instead of trying to construct some `parent_path(@parent)` as I was...

Comment: ya. would do if I *could*. SO won't let me accept my *own* answer for two (2) days... so go ahead and make you're own answer and *maybe* i'll accept it if it's more interesting than what I got...